# About behaviors of redirections with named pipe, grep and file redirections

Tags: bash, grep, io-redirection, tee

I have a question about the behavior of my bash command. I want to grep twice the same flux from stdout to 2 different files. To do so, I did:

```
./prog | tee >(grep -i 'grep1' > file1) | grep -i 'grep2' > file2
```

But my file2 is empty. I thought my `grep -i 'grep2'` did not catch anything but if I just type:

```
./prog | tee >(grep -i 'grep1' > file1) | grep -i 'grep2'
```

I do have my attented result:

```
[grep2] mylog...
[grep2] mylog...
[grep2] mylog...
```

I manage to write in my two files with this command:

```
./prog | tee >(grep -i 'grep1' > file1) >(grep -i 'grep2' > file2)
```

but I have to add `> /dev/null` at the end, to not have any output in stdout.

My question is, why does the redirection after the second grep is not catch by my `file2` redirection and why do I have to add another named pipe to do so ?

Comment: +1 nice usage of `tee`, the right tool!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the answer of Kent and use his example using `seq` I found the problem was my program.
My program behave as a deamon so the last pipe for the last redirection was not forked as the first one and so did nothing until the end of the program.

So I already had the right solution, using 2 named pipes for the 2 redirections:

```
./prog | tee >(grep -i 'grep1' > file1) >(grep -i 'grep2' > file2)
```

Answer (score 2):

you are almost there. try this:

```
./prog | tee >(grep -i 'grep1' > file1) >(grep -i 'grep2' > file2)
```

if you want to skip the stdout output, do

```
./prog | tee >(grep -i 'grep1' > file1) >(grep -i 'grep2' > file2) > /dev/null
```

for example:

```
kent$  seq 30|tee >(grep 2 >a) >(grep 3 > b) > /dev/null                                                                                                                    

kent$  head a b
==> a <==
2
12
20
21
22
23
24
25
26
27

==> b <==
3
13
23
30
```

Comment: I already found this solution but is there a way to avoid using the second named pipe and so the /dev/null redirection ?

Comment: @Turgal I just tested `seq 30|tee >(grep 2 >a) | grep 3 > b` it worked here under bash....   :$

Comment: Funny, it works too with the `seq` command but not with my program... It creates an empty file even if my second grep is the same as the first one (which is redirecting right to my file1)